# How to fix PHP code running painfully slow?

Tags: php

Here is my code

```
$facebook_from_file = file_get_contents('path/to/file');
$facebookfiles = explode(',', $facebook_from_file);
for($i = 1; $i <= 2; $i++) {
    $facebookfile = array_rand($facebookfiles);
    $filename = "http://sitename.com/".$facebookfiles[$facebookfile];
    outputtags($filename);
}
```

Similar code is executed 8 times to get random webpages from different directory. This code takes 8 seconds to execute. Is something wrong with this code? I think I should mention I am using iPage shared hosting. Are iPage servers slow?

This is the code for `outputtags()`

```
function outputtags($filename, $other, $programming)
{
  $html = file_get_contents_curl($filename);
  $doc = new DOMDocument();
  @$doc->loadHTML($html);
  $nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title');
  $title = $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
  $metas = $doc->getElementsByTagName('meta');
  for ($i = 0; $i < $metas->length; $i++) {
    $meta = $metas->item($i);
    if ($meta->getAttribute('property') == 'og:title')
      $ogtitle = $meta->getAttribute('content');
    if ($meta->getAttribute('property') == 'og:image')
      $ogimage = $meta->getAttribute('content');
    if ($other) {
      if ($meta->getAttribute('property') == 'og:description')
        $ogdescription = $meta->getAttribute('content');
    }
  }
  echo '<p style="margin:0;"><a href=' . $filename . ' target=_blank>' . $ogtitle . '</a></p>';
  if (!$other)
    echo '<a href=' . $filename . ' target=_blank><img style="margin:0 0 40px 0;" src="' . $ogimage . '" alt=""></a></br>';
  if ($other) {
    if (!$programming)
      echo '<a href=' . $filename . ' target=_blank><img src="' . $ogimage . '" alt=""></a></br>';
    echo '<p style="margin:0 0 40px 0;">' . $ogdescription . '</p>';
  }
}
```

This is file_get_contents_curl()

```
function file_get_contents_curl($url)
{
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
  $data = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  return $data;
}
```

Comment: Is `path/to/file` a local file? And what's `outputtags()`?

Comment: What exactly does `outputtags()` do? Does it actually fetch content from the url in `$filename`? If so thats probably the issue - you're essentially loading that page over http. And how large is the file referenced by `path/to/file`?

Comment: `path/to/file` is local file `outputtags()`  extracts meta tags from the url in `$filename`

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for your webhost, but shared hosts in general are not great. You're "sharing" all that server's resources with other users/customers. That's CPU, RAM and bandwidth.

All hosts oversell, and certain hosts will overcrowd servers. That said, 8 webpages in 8 seconds doesn't sound all that bad.

Switching to a VPS with uncontended bandwidth would probably help, although that is dependant upon the website you're scraping having sufficient bandwidth (the problem could be on the other end).

If you have a fast broadband connection at home or work, try installing Apache or XAMPP and testing your script locally. If it's fast, your host's the issue.

Another point worth bearing in mind is that the target site might be limiting your connections if you're hammering them with requests.

Answer (score 0):

If they don't need actual request properties then you can probably get away with using include to pull the content:

```
// you would add this function and then replace your call 
// to file_get_contents_curl() with it
function file_get_contents_php($filename) {
    ob_start();
    include($filename);
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

If they do depend on the request properties or might impact something on the page that's trying to load them then that probably isn't a good idea.

The most ideal solution is that since this is just meta content, to store it in a database or configuration file somewhere that you can load from anywhere with little consequence. you might have a file called `metas.json`:

```
{
   "/facebook/file/url_1.php": {
       "title": "Url 1",
       "og": {
           "title": "Url 1",
           "description": "This is the og:description for url_1.php",
           "image": "http://somesite.com/path/to/url1/image.jpg"
       }
   },
   "/facebook/file/url_2.php": {
       "title": "Url 2",
       "og": {
           "title": "Url 2",
           "description": "This is the og:description for url_2.php",
           "image": "http://somesite.com/path/to/url2/image.jpg"
       }
   },
   "/facebook/file/url_3.php": {
       "title": "Url 3",
       "og": {
           "title": "Url 3",
           "description": "This is the og:description for url_3.php",
           "image": "http://somesite.com/path/to/url3/image.jpg"
       }
   },
   "/facebook/file/url_4.php": {
       "title": "Url 4",
       "og": {
           "title": "Url 4",
           "description": "This is the og:description for url_4.php",
           "image": "http://somesite.com/path/to/url4/image.jpg"
       }
   }
}
```

In these pages you could then simply create a function like this:

```
/**
 * Get a hash of meta tags for a page URI
 *
 * Returns an associative array of tags and values or false
 * if the URI is not present in configuration.
 *
 * @param String $uri    The URI of the page
 * @return Array|Boolean
 */
function get_metas($uri) {
    $json = file_get_contents('/path/to/metas.json');
    $metas = json_decode($json, true);
    
    return $metas && isset($metas[$uri]) 
        ? $metas[$uri]
        : false;
}

/**
 * Includes meta tags for a URI
 *
 * @param String $uri    The URI of the page
 * @return void
 */    
function include_meta_tags($uri) {
    if (false !== ($metas = get_meta_tags($uri))) {
        echo $metas;
    }
}

/**
 * Gets an HTML string of meta tags for a URI
 *
 * @param String $uri  The URI of the page
 * @return String|Boolean
 */
function get_meta_tags($uri) {
    $metas = get_metas($uri);
  
    if (!$metas) {
       return false;
    }

    $tags = array();
    if (isset($metas['title'])) {
        $tags[] = sprintf('<title>%s</title>', $metas['title']);
    }

    if (isset($metas['og']) {
       foreach ($metas['og'] as $property => $value) {
           $tags[] = sprintf('<meta property="og:%s" content="%s">', $property, $value);
       }
    }

    return impolde("\n", $tags);
}
```

So then in the head of all your pages you could do:

```
<?php echo include_meta_tags($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>
```

And then your outputtags function would look like:

```
function outputtags($uri, $other = null, $programming = null) {
    $metas = get_metas($uri);

    $ogtitle = isset($metas['og']['title'])
         ? $metas['og']['title']
         : $metas['title'];

    $ogdescription = isset($metas['og']['description'])
         ? $metas['og']['description']
         : $metas['title'];
    
    $ogimage = isset($metas['og']['image'])
         ? $metas['og']['image']
         : '';

    // now your existing logic for outputting the markup
    printf(
        '<p style="margin:0;"><a href="%s" target="_blank">%s</a></p>'
        $uri,
        $ogtitle
    );

    if (!$other) {
        printf(
           '<a href="%s" target="_blank"><img style="margin:0 0 40px 0;" src="%s" alt="" /></a><br />'
           $uri,
           $ogimage
        );
    } else {
      if (!$programming) {
          printf(
              '<a href="%s" target=_blank><img src="%s" alt="" /></a></br>',
              $uri,
              $ogimage
          );
          printf('<p style="margin:0 0 40px 0;">%s</p>', $ogdescription);
      }
    }
  
}
```

---

> `outputtags()` extracts meta tags from the url in `$filename`

Well there is your issue most likely. This is essentially the same thing as hitting the URL with your web browser - you have to wait for the other web server to serve the file as it normally would so the response time is going vary greatly and the total time it take to serve your page is going to be at a minimum the time it takes to access those 8 remote URLs.

If you really need to do this you could use cURL so you have some control over the timeout and what not, but over all you are still going to be at the mercy of the response times of the other servers.

### Update

> But both files are on same domain. Is there anything I can do about it?
>
> Yes, the webpage from which code is executed is the same as from where the $filename is extracted.

Then yes. Access them via the filesystem not via url. I don't know what `outputtags` does internally but I assume you are using `file_get_contents` inside.

So instead of supplying a URL supply a file path. Looks like the files you are getting the meta tags from are all listed from the document root of your site so it may be as easy as:

```
for($i=1;$i<=2;$i++){
    $facebookfile = array_rand($facebookfiles);
    // filename is now something like
    // /var/www/site.com/the_face_book_file.html
    $filename = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $facebookfiles[$facebookfile];
    outputtags($filename);
}
```

Of course if these are .php files that need to be processed then you may be out of luck depending on how they work.

Comment: But both files are on same domain. Is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: The same domain, and more importantly, filesystem as the code you posted that is trying to access them?

Comment: Yes, the webpage from which code is executed is the same as from where the $filename is extracted.

Comment: Do the file you are loading have php in them that needs to be interpreted?

Comment: The files just have code like `<?php require_once("../../templates/footer.php")?>` which just includes pure HTML so that I don't have to rewrite same code again and again.